# Responsive FIlemanager, upload images ckeditor isssues

Tags: php, image, upload, ckeditor, responsive-filemanager

I am using Responsive Filemanager for the first time in my life and I'm new at programming in php (5 months), I'm learning all by my self, with that I want to say previously that I'm sorry if I will ask something basic or "stupid".

I created a CMS where I added a CKeditor editor. Yesterday I was looking for some program for upload images, and I found Responsive Filemanager.

I installed Filemanager normally (I think that I haven't done anything wrong).

I change the directories for the ones that I want to, and I saw on the internet that I needed to change the file permission and folder permission to 0766.

Right know I can upload images directly from the filemanager, but when I'm going to select the image, the image appears in a red background an "x" (I can see the thumb correctly and if I add an image directly to the folder I can use that image without any error).

One more time sorry if my question is basic ou doesn't make any sense, but can somebody help to solve the situation?

P.S: sorry if my English isn't very good.

IMAGE (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyQFX.png):

```php
    'upload_dir' => '/admin/cms/admin/ckeditor/samples/uploads/',

    'current_path' => '../uploads/',

    'thumbs_base_path' => '../thumbs/',

    'thumbs_upload_dir' => '/thumbs/',


    'filePermission' => 0766,
    'folderPermission' => 0766,
```

Comment: You probably need to check your folders... that usually happens when the filemanager can't find the picture... check the full URL and see if its correct...